# What is the strongest filament to use?

Tags: filament

I'm looking for a strong filament that can handle a large tension load and no bending deformation when a perpendicular force is applied to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What application do you have in mind?

Comment: Hi, Aaron! Could you please provide some more information of the application you need this filament for, or some other requirements in general. Should it bend or break? Should it handle particular weather conditions? Etc..

Comment: Due to the lack of specificity and activity on this question, I will put it *on hold* until further improvements are made. Feel free to improve the question so that we can reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

Carbon or glass fiber reinforced PLA likely has the strongest without deformation. PLA will snap before deforming.

Fiber reinforced ABS is also an option. ABS is stronger but will bend before breaking.

Both are hard on nozzles and may require a stainless steel nozzle.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Nylon filaments are among the strongest. I'd look at the technical specs of [Taulman3D's Filament](http://taulman3d.com/index.html). They're the only nylon I've ever tried, and I know they have in-depth specs of how their filament holds up. I'm sure you can find other providers, though.

Comment: The question asks for "large tension load" and "no bending deformation". While Nylon is indeed very good for the first requirement, it's actually rather flexible so it's not a good fit for the second requirement. In this case, not enough information is contained in the question to properly answer it (since it is not clear what trade off between tensile strength and rigidity is desired) so therefore it might be helpful to request clarification before attempting to answer the question.